# How to change file mime type to bypass php shell upload?

Tags: php, linux, security, shell

I am testing my friends site. It allows only jpeg to be uploaded in upload script. The checking is done like this
following script is run

```
file --mime-type --brief filename
```

Only if this gives image/jpeg its allowing the upload. How can I upload a php ? Basically i need to spoof this mime type?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: We will not help you hack websites under the guise of "helping a friend". If he needs security testing, he can hire someone that knows the basics of web security.

Comment: I have access to the code. I am not hacking!

Comment: If you simply want to test what happens if someone gets a PHP file past his mime-type check, then put a PHP file in the upload folder and pretend it happened. You don't need the answer to this question. If you're honestly curious, then spend 10 minutes learning how MIME types are determined instead of asking for code.

Comment: So you have the codes yet you intentionally want to put a bug in your friends script.... How nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m not giving you a working solution but just a hint: The JPEG format consists of different parts, some are required and some are optional. Among those optional parts, some allow to store arbitrary data.

If you manage to alter such a part of an existing JPEG image or to add one and put your PHP code to it, you have an JPEG image with embedded PHP code that should be recognized as a proper JPEG image. Then all you have to do is to get that code invoked.